# JavaScript: Popup windows closes immediately

Tags: javascript

I am trying to close all open pop-up using javascript. I tried the following code but it didn't work.

This is my code for opening the pop-up window..

```
var childWindow = new Array();  
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) 
{    
    var left = (screen.width/2) - (w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2) - (h/2);
    var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
    childWindow[childWindow.length] = targetWin;

    if (window.focus) {
        targetWin.focus()
    }

    return false;       
}
```

And this is my code for closing all open pop-up window..

```
function CloseChildWindow() 
{
   if (childWindow.length != 0) 
   {
       for (var i = 0; i < childWindow.length; i++) 
       {
           childWindow[i].close();
       }
    } 
}
```

I call the function 'CloseChildWindow()' in body onunload event of the page. But when I try to open the pop-up window it closes immediately so the pop-up window didn't open completely.

What is the problem with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nice piece of code there. Can you provide a jsfiddle with some random pop-ups.

Comment: Browser pop-up blocker?

Answer (score 0):

Pop-ups must be initiated by a user click. I'm assuming this isn't a problem for you, because you *are* seeing a popup, if only for a second. This means the browser isn't blocking it.

However, if you are doing this on click of a link, then the `onunload` event *will* fire... even if the page itself isn't unloaded! I had this as a major problem when working on a particularly ambitious project.

What you may need to do is add a "don't unload" flag, which gets set when a popup is opened and cleared after a `setTimeout`. Then, your `onunload` event can simply check that flag and do nothing if it is set.